# CSS Polygon Animation not working while hovering on the clip path

Tags: html, css, css-animations

A very simple example:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <img class="test" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1453728013993-6d66e9c9123a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8bGVuc3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" />
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.test:hover, .test:focus {
    clip-path: polygon(70% 0, 100% 30%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}
```

Whenever I hover on the image the animation works fine but when I hover on the clip path it breaks and the full image is displayed, which is wrong. Kindly help me to maintain the animation while I hover on the clip path as well.

I want to achieve the below animation on hover, which is working:

[image]

But when I try to hover my mouse towards the below direction, the animation hides but I want that the animation should be maintained.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please be more clear.

Comment: @talha2k - Please check the new added description. Kindly let me know if something more is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put image in container then use hover on container with image

```css
.test {
  
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
}
.test:hover .img  {
  clip-path: polygon(70% 0, 100% 30%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<body>
    
    <div class="test">
      <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1453728013993-6d66e9c9123a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8bGVuc3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" />
    </div>
    
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mask if you don't want an extra wrapper:

```css
img:hover {
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(-145deg,#0000 15%,#000 0);
}
```

```html
<img class="test" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1453728013993-6d66e9c9123a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8bGVuc3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" >
```

Comment: Implemented your change but the quality of linear gradient is not as good as clip-path. I can see many edges above the image.

Comment: @HarshSharma you can play with the percentage to fix this, ex: change the 0 with 15.5%